# Display image from cache with async call of ajax() jquery function

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, caching

For my project, i would like display cached image dynamically with an async call by ajax() jquery function.

```
$.ajax({
    type: “POST”,
    url: “mypage.aspx/GetThumbnail”,
    data: “{‘id’:'" + idThumbnail + "’}”,
    contentType: “application/json; charset=utf-8?,
    dataType: “json”,
    success: function(msg) {
       // Hide the fake progress indicator graphic.
       $('#thumbnailContent').removeClass('loading');

       // Insert the returned HTML into the <div>.
       $('#thumbnailContent').html(msg.d);
    }
});
```

This JQuery block code will asynchronously call an static webmethod "GetThumbnail" of "mypage.aspx" page, if is a success so the return of my webmethod will be display as html like this :

```
<img url="myThumbnailImage.jpg" />
```

My problem come from the static webmethod which should return formatted html on a string, but when i read data from cache i recover byte[] like this :

```
if (HttpContext.Current.Cache[id_thumbnail+ "_thumbnail"] != null)
  {
  byte[] mytemptabbyte = (byte[])HttpContext.Current.Cache[id_thumbnail + "_thumbnail"];
  HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
  HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "image/jpeg");
  HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("");
  HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(mytemptabbyte);
  HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
  HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
  }
```

How can do return html formatted response with my cached image ?

EDIT:

So i call a new aspx page can i do like this ?

```
function LoadThumnail(id_thumbnail){
  $.ajax({
    type: “POST”,
    url: “getThumbnail.aspx?id_thumbnail=”id_thumbnail,
    data: “{}”,
    contentType: “application/json; charset=utf-8?,
    dataType: “json”,
    success: function(msg) {

       // Insert the returned HTML into the <div>.
       $('#thumbnailContent').html('<img src="' + msg.d + '" />);

       // Hide the fake progress indicator graphic.
       $('#thumbnailContent').removeClass('loading');
    }
});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Create a page (e.g. getimage.aspx), and place the code that you called "getting image from cache" to OnInit/Page_Init of that page.

Then, have the IMG tag be something like this:

```
<img url="getimage.aspx?id=myThumbnailImage.jpg" />
```

or

```
<img url="getimage.aspx?id=1234" />
```

Then, also, read the `Request.QueryString["id"]` and use it to retrive the image from cache.

Comment: Ok but by doing like this, this is not async call and i would like load thumbnail on demand...

Comment: @bor1s call the mentioned page by ajax asyncronously. then the ajax request will always get the string representation.

Comment: apples and pears, gentlemen. he said his ajax call goes for that img tag html. I'm suggesting to change that markup, so that he can utilize image data that sits in memory, as those images do not exist. Alternative is to save the image data to disk, then worry or not to worry about cleanup.